# How do I change the background of a paragraph to a random color on click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the background color whenever you click on one of the 3 paragraphs. I used a random color generator function and used jQuery to change the background color of the paragraph on click. However, I am not sure what I am doing wrong now.

Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vo7rs09g/

```
p {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:blue;
}

<script>

  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

    $('p').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color',randomColor());
    });
};
```

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('p').click(function() {
        
        $(this).css('background-color',"#"+randomColor());
    })
    
    function randomColor() {
        
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        
    }
})
```

```css
 p {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: time to learn to give more informative descriptions than *'try this'*.

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to call a variable as a function. Instead you should turn what was a variable into a function:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo7rs09g/12/)

```
// This should be a function (not var)
function randomColor() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}    

// When you call the function, it returns the 6 digit value, but it needs a "#" in front for it to be a color value. Be sure to attach that
$('p').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', "#" + randomColor());
});
```

---

Also, in your original JS Fiddle you didn't load jquery, and you had an extra `};` at the end that caused a syntax error.

Comment: Ah, that clears things up a lot now about how you were saying that I was calling a variable rather than a function.

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN use RGB just random 3 numbers from 0 to 255
EXPLAINS : 0 = (black) , 255 = (white)

```
var randomColor = function() {
  var color = "RGB("+Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + ", ";
  color += Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + ", ";
  color += Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + ")";
  return color;
}

$('p').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color',randomColor());
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7016/)

Answer (score 1):

I checked it on the fiddle. You havent included the jquery file first. and second the '};' is also extra if you see. I added jquery and removed the }; thing. It worked fine.

And your code will give a random color, but the same random color to each. If you want a random color for each of the box, place the var randomcolor thing in your p.click function

Answer (score 0):

you miss '#' and the 'randomColor' is not a function,and if you want random color,you should set random inside,like this:

```
        $('p').click(function() {
        var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        $(this).css('background-color','#'+randomColor);
    });
```